# Subtract year and month

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following query

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(MONTH,-1, GETDATE()),112),6)
```

Which will result in: 201708 (as of getdate() today)

I need to also subtract a year from this, so it will be come: 201608

I tried adding another DATEADD function but I can't get it to work.

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where exactly did you try to include the second `DATEADD`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there, I think you need:

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(6),DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATEADD(MONTH,-1, GETDATE())),112),6)
```

When you define a `varchar` (in a convert, create or any other way) you should **always** define the length as well.

Comment: Thank you, so helpful! Exactly what I need. Good suggestion to also add a (6) behind varchar!

Answer (score 0):

I find this alternative to be easier to follow.  This produces a number:

```
select year(getdate()) * 100 + month(getdate())
```

You can convert this to a string (if you really need it):

```
select convert(varchar(255), year(getdate()) * 100 + month(getdate()))
```

To subtract a year:

```
select convert(varchar(255), (year(getdate()) - 1) * 100 + month(getdate()))
```